# How To Determine Inbound Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, file-replication-services

We are using ultrasound to monitor FRS on a Window 2003 Domain. Domain's Functional Level is 2003 Native. Ultrasound keeps reporting on a mystery connection that is causing the backlog in our replica set.

The big mystery is that the only thing Ultrasound can tell me about the connection is what the outbound server is. There is no information about what the Inbound Server is, even though the connection health rating for both inbound & outbound is Green.

I suspect this is correlated to the alerts being received about a long Version Vector Join (VVJoin) occurring. It is true we recently promoted a DC, however it appears to be replicating fine with another server within it's site.

Is there a way for me to work out what this "Unknown" inbound server is with a command? or will it just mysteriously go away?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that you need to patient as it sounds like the new DC hasn't fully replicated into the AD.

The command line tools you want to look at are [ntfrsutl.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755455%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [dcdiag.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773199(WS.10).aspx) which are part of the Windows Server Support tools.

Comment: Isn't grand when someone you work with answers your question without realising who it is? :) As discussed Ultrasound & netdiag answered the riddle - so big tick ;)